# How do I download only my purchase invoice documents from Exact Online with Invantive Query Tool?

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-query-tool

To comply to regulations, I'm trying to download the purchase invoice documents (as PDF files) from some of my divisions to save them on-disk for archiving purposes.

I use Invantive Query Tool to do this. I like to know which table to use and how to export these attachments only regarding purchase invoice documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed do this by using the export options in Invantive Query Tool or Invantive Data Hub.

What you need is a query that hooks up the document information of type 20 (purchase invoices) with the actual attachment files. You can find a list of types and their description in the [`DocumentTypes`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-documents-documenttypes.html) view. You can find the document attachment files in the [`DocumentAttachmentFiles`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-documents-documentattachmentfiles.html) table.

When you have retrieved that, you can export the documents from that query to disk using a `local export documents` statement.

The full query is here:

```
use 123456

select /*+ join_set(dae, document, 10000) */ attachmentfromurl
,      dct.division || '/' || dae.id || '-' || filename 
       filepath
from   exactonlinerest..documents dct
join   DocumentAttachmentFiles dae
on     dae.division = dct.division
and    dae.document = dct.id
where  dct.Type = 20
order
by     dct.division
,      dae.id

local export documents in attachmentfromurl to "c:\temp\docs" filename column Filepath
```

Make sure to set the ID of the division right in the [`use`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/invantive-bridge/webhelp/invantive-sql-grammar.html#usestatement) statement (this is the technical ID, not the 'division number', which can contain duplicates). You can find that in the top menu bar under *Partitions*. Or simply use `use all` to get the documents from all divisions (this might take a while).

Also set the file path right where it says `c:\temp\docs` now. Then hit F5 in the Query Tool to execute, or run the script from Data Hub.